# In detectron2, how could I plot only bounding on images without label (class name) in object detection?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, detectron

I am learning detectron2 and practicing it using pokemonster data.
So, I follow the detectron2 tutorial (here : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5)

And also a detector is developed and below image can be detected.

[image]

But, in this image, red circle is class name. I want to plot only bounding box(green color) with the exception of red circle (class name).
Now below is my code for visualization. What code should be modified?
Thank you.

```
import glob
for imageName in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(test_path, '*.jpg'))):
  im = cv2.imread(imageName)
  outputs = predictor(im)
  v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
                metadata=train_metadata,
                scale=0.8
                 )
  out = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
  boxes = v._convert_boxes(outputs["instances"].pred_boxes.to('cpu'))
  for box in boxes:
    box = (round(box[0]), round(box[1]), round(box[2]) - round(box[0]), round(box[3] - box[1]))
    out = v.draw_text(f"{box[2:4]}", (box[0], box[1]))
  cv2_imshow(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class [`Visualizer`](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/modules/utils.html#detectron2.utils.visualizer.Visualizer) contains all the methods inlcuding [`draw_box()`](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/modules/utils.html#detectron2.utils.visualizer.Visualizer.draw_text). You want to draw all the boxes to your `Visualizer` object and finally return a `VisImage`

```
v = Visualizer(
        im[:, :, ::-1], 
        metadata=train_metadata, 
        scale=0.8,
        )
for box in outputs["instances"].pred_boxes.to('cpu'):
    v.draw_box(box)
    v.draw_text(str(box[:2].numpy()), tuple(box[:2].numpy()))
v = v.get_output()
img =  v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]
cv2_imshow(img)
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. But your code only show bounding box. I want to plot bounding box coordinate like above with bounding box. Could you please help me more?

Comment: Yes sure, i updated my answer, you can draw whatever you want...

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to draw binary mask, but there is no function to draw mask on the colored image. How to draw mask on the original input color image.

```
output = predictor(input_image)        
V = Visualizer(input_image[:, :, ::-1], 
MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TRAIN[0]), scale = 1.2)
mask=output["instances"].get("pred_masks")
mask=mask.to("cpu")
V.draw_instance_predictions(output["instances"].to("cpu"))
for m in mask:
    V.draw_mask(m)

V = V.get_output()
cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, V.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of boxes and masks:

```
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
               metadata=train_metadata, 
               scale=0.8,
)
# Boxes
for box in outputs["instances"].pred_boxes.to('cpu'):
    v.draw_box(box)    
# Masks
for mask in outputs["instances"].pred_masks.to('cpu'):
    v.draw_soft_mask(mask)
v = v.get_output()
img =  v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1]
cv2_imshow(img)
```